# How do I script my table to generate INSERT INTO commands?

Tags: sql

I have a lookup table with about 10 records, I know I can script the structure to a text file, but how can I script the data to insert into commands?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: some sample data and a detailed description of what should happen to that data will get you a useful answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting data In SQL Server as INSERT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server...

SQL Management Studio will generate an insert script.  Right-click your database and select Tasks-Export data

Comment: Note that this is supported from version 2008 onwards

Answer (score 5):

Ten records, and it's urgent?

Just type it out manually.  Should be pretty easy to cut-n-paste.

Answer (score 2):

This depends pretty much on the tools you are using...

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way is to run a select into a string and tell sql enterprise manager to give you text (not grid) as the output

SELECT 'INSERT INTO TABLES (fields here) VALUES (' + field1 + ', '....

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
select "insert into my_targ_table(my_field_1, my_field_2, ..., my_field_n) values(" || x.my_field_1_col || ", " || x.my_field_2_col || ");"
from my_source_table x
```

Then just run the script you've generated.

Comment: I had the same idea, only 28 seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with all tables

```
DECLARE @TblName varchar(128)
DECLARE @WhereClause varchar(255)
DECLARE @cmd1 varchar(7000) 
DECLARE @cmd2 varchar(7000)

SET @TblName = '<tablename>' --Name of your table
SET @WhereClause = ' ' --where clause ex columnA = 1
SET @cmd1 = 'SELECT '' INSERT INTO ' + @TblName + ' ( '
SET @cmd2 = ' + '' VALUES ( '' + '

create table #tableDef (id int identity (1,1), ColType int, ColName varchar(128))

--Fetch column names and datatypes
insert  #tableDef (ColType, ColName)
select case when DATA_TYPE like '%char%' then 1
            when DATA_TYPE like '%datetime%' then 2 
            else 0 end ,
    COLUMN_NAME
from    information_schema.columns
where   TABLE_NAME = @TblName
order by ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT @cmd1 = @cmd1 + ColName + ',',
       @cmd2 = @cmd2
                + ' CASE WHEN ' + ColName + ' IS NULL '
                +   ' THEN ''NULL'' '
                +   ' ELSE '
                +     case ColType 
                      when  1 then  ''''''''' + ' + ColName + ' + ''''''''' 
                      when  2 then  ''''''''' + ' + 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),' + ColName + ')' + ' + '''''''''                    
                      else 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),' + ColName + ')' end
                + ' END + '','' + '
        from    #tableDef
order by id

select @cmd1 = left(@cmd1,len(@cmd1)-1) + ' ) '' '
select @cmd2 = left(@cmd2,len(@cmd2)-8) + '+'')'' FROM ' + @tblName + @WhereClause

select '/*' + @cmd1 + @cmd2 + '*/'
exec (@cmd1 + @cmd2)

drop table #tableDef
```