# Export data from MSSQL to H2 database

Tags: ssms, h2

I am working on data (data from tables only) conversion from MSSQL database to H2 database. Data model is the same except maybe a few minor changes.

My first idea was to export data from tables as INSERT INTO statements ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into)), and  run these after some adjustments on the H2 database. But I ran into a problem with datetime, MSSQL exported this as a number casted like datetime:

```
CAST(0x000092AC00000000 AS DateTime)
```

And H2 doesn't seem to understand this. Is there a way to make this solution work (force SSMS to export the datetime a different way so H2 can read it)? I am using SSMS 2008 R2.
I'm also open to other suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: There are two problem: H2 doesn't support such hex number, you would need to write `CAST(X'000092AC00000000' AS LONG)` to convert the hex value to a long (bigint). The second problem is that H2 doesn't support casting numbers to dates. I wonder what the number means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried  Open DB Copy? 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendbcopy/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually managed to make a simple .NET application, which selects the data from the MSSQL, and then create a batch of inserts to H2 database. It's a really ugly solution, but it worked fine for me.

Comment: Open DB Copy doesn't support H2

Comment: It does. H2 is not included in the list of databases OpenDB Copy ships with. You have to add it yourself. Please read the OpenDB Copy user manual.