# How to recreate database from scripts in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Refer to [Exporting data In SQL Server as INSERT INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into?answertab=active#tab-top)

Recently, my client gave me 40 `.sql` files, I believe he generated them by above method.

I look at the first `.sql` file, it contains `create database`, `create table`, and many `insert` statements.

How can I use these `.sql` files to recreate the whole database? We are using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Run the scripts?  What have you tried?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: it has 40 sql script files, I use sqlcmd to run the first script and has some errors, anyway I will try to use sqlcmd -e to see what really happen.

Comment: I see, the sql files is utf8 file and it contain unicode data, I force it to use utf-8 codepage by -f 65001 ---> SQLCMD -S mywindows\sqlexpress -i abcdb001.sql -f 65001    , no errors

Comment: No errors is good, but did it work?  What did happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express!

http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=7593