# How to do ready made insert query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table have many data. I want to pay these data to user by sql insert query. Not excel or other format , want to get only insert query. Is it possible ? How can I export these data .

Comment: you have data in which format?

Comment: @ Zeeshan thank for answer .I found solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into