# Generate SQL Compact database from Sql Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, local-database

I wish to migrate from my SQL Server database to a SQL Server Compact database. I have tens of tables with tons of columns, it will be a life-time taking process to generate the tables and their fields manually from scratch.

Is there some faster way to generate the tables from SQL Server?

Comment: You could try `Generate Scripts` option which can generate schema as well as with data also.

Comment: @VishalSuthar can you give me a point to start from?

Comment: You can refer this: [Generate a Script (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx) and also this: [Exporting data In SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515975)

Comment: @VishalSuthar I generated the scripts from Database, how can I run them on my local database (.sdf database in visual studio)?