# EF Code First Generate C# Seed Method from Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a database that is populated with test data. The table relation is complex and therefore I would like to know if I can generate c# code for inserting that data.

Basically I want to export all that data a C# method Seed that will populate it back when code first migration is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the package management console, enter the following command:

```
enable-migrations
```

It will enable the configuration part of EF and includes a `Seed` method. If this is not enough there are more options you can explore, like `add-migration` to add a custom migration.

See this post for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx or
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

When using a `Code Based Migration`, you can query for data, remove it and re-insert it any way you like.

Comment: But - how can I get data from database to c# code using migrations? There is not something my data in Migration folder.. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Alamakanambra: You can use the basic database functions to generate a script. This can be used by migrations or something else. See this post for MS-SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515975/2416958

Comment: Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database 
these are the commands I use in dev to get my database seeded