# programmatically generate script for a table

Tags: sql-server, copy

I learned how to generate script for a table.

Eg for this table:

[image]

to generate script like this (I omitted something):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[singer_and_album](
    [singer] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [album_title] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[test_double_quote] ([singer], [album_title]) VALUES (N'Adale', N'19')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[test_double_quote] ([singer], [album_title]) VALUES (N'Michael Jaskson', N'Thriller"')
GO
```

I tried programmatically generating the script using [this shell code](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/71569b94-ec97-444a-b68c-ec2a87c7b6df/example-scripting-data-with-smo-and-powershell?forum=sqlsmoanddmo). And got error:

> PS
>   SQLSERVER:\SQL\DESKTOP-KHTRJOJ\MSSQL\Databases\yzhang\Tables\dbo.test_double_quote>
>   C:\Users\yzhang\Documents\script_out_table.ps1 "DESKTOP-KHTRJOJ\MSSQL"
>   "yzhang" "dbo" "test_double_quote",
>   "C:\Users\yzhang\Documents\script_out.sql"
>
> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "EnumScript" and the argument
>   count: "1". At C:\Users\yzhang\Documents\script_out_table.ps1:41
>   char:16
>   + foreach ($s in $scripter.EnumScript($tbl.Urn)) { write-host $s }
>   +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Anybody can help? I don't know much about shell.
btw is shell the only way to generate scripts? Can we do it with some sql code? Thank you--

---

FYI, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into?noredirect=1&lq=1) for how to manually generate script. In my case (sql server 2016 management studio) it's like

1. right click the database name (not table name) -> `Tasks` -> `Generate scripts`

[image]

2. choose a table or all tables
3. click `advanced` and select `schema and data`
   [image]

Comment: which programming laguages you can code so we can provide an alternate.

Comment: Thank you @ImranAliKhan. I'm familiar with Python/R/sql. If somebody can tell me how to change the shell code, that would be nice too (I don't understand too much shell so I'll mechanically use it)

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: There are some comments at the bottom of the [article where you got the Powershell script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/71569b94-ec97-444a-b68c-ec2a87c7b6df/example-scripting-data-with-smo-and-powershell?forum=sqlsmoanddmo) that talk about the "multiple overloads" error and how they fixed by removing the `.Urn` reference: `foreach ($s in $scripter.EnumScript($tbl))`

Answer (score 5):

this is a sql script to genrate table script

```
declare @vsSQL varchar(8000)
declare @vsTableName varchar(50)
select @vsTableName = '_PRODUCT'--- Your Table Name here

select @vsSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @vsTableName + char(10) + '(' + char(10)

select @vsSQL = @vsSQL + ' ' + sc.Name + ' ' +
st.Name +
case when st.Name in ('varchar','varchar','char','nchar') then '(' + cast(sc.Length as varchar) + ') ' else ' ' end +
case when sc.IsNullable = 1 then 'NULL' else 'NOT NULL' end + ',' + char(10)
from sysobjects so
join syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id
join systypes st on st.xusertype = sc.xusertype
where so.name = @vsTableName
order by
sc.ColID

select substring(@vsSQL,1,len(@vsSQL) - 2) + char(10) + ')'
```

**Edit:** c# code

```
public string GetScript(string strConnectionString
                      , string strObject
                      , int ObjType)
{
    string strScript = null;
    int intCounter = 0;
    if (ObjType != 0)
    {
        ObjSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString.Trim());

        try
        {
            ObjDataSet = new DataSet();
            ObjSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("exec sp_helptext 
                [" + strObject + "]", ObjSqlConnection);
            ObjSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            ObjSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = ObjSqlCommand;
            ObjSqlDataAdapter.Fill(ObjDataSet);

            foreach (DataRow ObjDataRow in ObjDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                strScript += Convert.ToString(ObjDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[intCounter][0]);
                intCounter++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           strScript = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            ObjSqlDataAdapter = null;
            ObjSqlCommand = null;
            ObjSqlConnection = null;
        }
    }

    return strScript;
}
```

To create Insert script use this store procedure

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects 
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[InsertGenerator]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertGenerator]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[InsertGenerator]
(
@tableName varchar(100),
@KeyColumn1 varchar(100)='',
@KeyColumn2 varchar(100)=''
)
AS

-- Generating INSERT statements in SQL Server
-- to validate if record exists - supports 2 field Unique index

--Declare a cursor to retrieve column specific information for the specified table
DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT column_name,data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @tableName

OPEN cursCol

DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) --for storing the first half of INSERT statement
DECLARE @stringData nvarchar(max) --for storing the data (VALUES) related statement
DECLARE @dataType nvarchar(1000) --data types returned for respective columns
DECLARE @FieldVal nvarchar(1000) -- save value for the current field
DECLARE @KeyVal nvarchar(1000) -- save value for the current field
DECLARE @KeyTest0 nvarchar(1000) -- used to test if key exists
DECLARE @KeyTest1 nvarchar(1000) -- used to test if key exists
DECLARE @KeyTest2 nvarchar(1000) -- used to test if key exists

SET @KeyTest0=''

IF @KeyColumn1<>''
SET @KeyTest0='IF not exists (Select * from '+@tableName

SET @KeyTest1=''
SET @KeyTest2=''

SET @string='INSERT '+@tableName+'('
SET @stringData=''
SET @FieldVal=''
SET @KeyVal=''

DECLARE @colName nvarchar(50)

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType

IF @@fetch_status<>0
begin
    print 'Table '+@tableName+' not found, processing skipped.'
    close curscol
    deallocate curscol
    return
END

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

IF @dataType in ('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar')
BEGIN
    SET @FieldVal=''''+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+'+@colName+'+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'
    SET @KeyVal='''+isnull('''''+'''''+'+@colName+'+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'
    SET @stringData=@stringData+@FieldVal
END

ELSE

if @dataType in ('text','ntext','xml') --if the datatype is text or something else 
BEGIN
    SET @FieldVal='''''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(max)),'''')+'''''',''+'
    SET @stringData=@stringData+@FieldVal
END
ELSE
IF @dataType = 'money' --because money doesn't get converted from varchar implicitly
BEGIN
    SET @FieldVal='''convert(money,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+'
    SET @stringData=@stringData+@FieldVal
END
ELSE 
IF @dataType='datetime'
BEGIN
    SET @FieldVal='''convert(datetime,'+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+',121)+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',121),''+'
    SET @stringData=@stringData+@FieldVal
END
ELSE 
IF @dataType='image' 
BEGIN
    SET @FieldVal='''''''''+isnull(cast(convert(varbinary,'+@colName+') as varchar(6)),''0'')+'''''',''+'
    SET @stringData=@stringData+@FieldVal
END
ELSE --presuming the data type is int,bit,numeric,decimal 
BEGIN
    SET @FieldVal=''''+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+')+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'
    SET @KeyVal='''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+')+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'
    SET @stringData=@stringData+@FieldVal
END

--Build key test
IF @KeyColumn1=@colName
begin
    SET @KeyTest1 = ' WHERE [' + @KeyColumn1 + ']='
    SET @KeyTest1 = @KeyTest1+@KeyVal+']'
end
IF @KeyColumn2=@colName
begin
    SET @KeyTest2 = ' AND [' + @KeyColumn2 + ']='
    SET @KeyTest2 = @KeyTest2+@KeyVal+']'
end

SET @string=@string+'['+@colName+'],'

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType
END

DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)

-- Build the test string to check if record exists
if @KeyTest0<>''
begin
    if @Keycolumn1<>''
        SET @KeyTest0 = @KeyTest0 + substring(@KeyTest1,0,len(@KeyTest1)-4)
    if @Keycolumn2<>''
    begin
        SET @KeyTest0 = @KeyTest0 + ''''
        SET @KeyTest0 = @KeyTest0 + substring(@KeyTest2,0,len(@KeyTest2)-4)
    end
    SET @KeyTest0 = @KeyTest0 + ''')'

    SET @query ='SELECT '''+substring(@KeyTest0,0,len(@KeyTest0)) + ') ' 
end
else
    SET @query ='SELECT '''+substring(@KeyTest0,0,len(@KeyTest0))

SET @query = @query + substring(@string,0,len(@string)) + ') ' 
SET @query = @query + 'VALUES(''+ ' + substring(@stringData,0,len(@stringData)-2)+'''+'')'' FROM '+@tableName

exec sp_executesql @query

CLOSE cursCol
DEALLOCATE cursCol

GO
```

and use of InsertGenerator like below

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[InsertGenerator]
        @tableName = N'_PRODUCT'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: thank you so much @ImranAliKhan. I suggest you leave the c# code there, so it can help someone else. I tested this code, it generates the code to make the table schema perfectly, but not to insert the data. Could you please add that part too, if possible? A maybe bigger problem is, the output string is a variable - my data has 20G I'm concerned about the length. I'll do some research about it too. Thank you so much-

Comment: Hi @ImranAliKhan I am also looking similar problem, need to generate selective stored procedures (300+) and generate script programmatically as it could be done many times. Can you please provide a solution so it  all goes to one text file.