# Have a CREATE TABLE or CREATE PROCEDURE automatically determine column type in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a database creation script that sets up tables, stored procedures, views, etc. When I change the type of a column in a create table statement, I want this change to be reflected in the create stored procedures / views / etc statements that reference that table without having to go through and manually change each one.

In other words I want my stored procedures to automatically determine the column type based on another column's type on creation. I don't need this to work on a live database with data, just while I'm iterating over the design and prototyping.

Something like a `TYPE_OF()` in this (fictional) example:

```
create table Logs
(
    id              int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    userName        varchar(32),
    logType         int foreign key references LogType(id),
    description     varchar(128),
    datestamp       datetime
);
go

create procedure WriteLog
(
    @userName       TYPE_OF(Logs.userName),   -- should be varchar(32),
    @logType        int,
    @description    TYPE_OF(Logs.description)    -- should be varchar(128)
)
as
begin

    insert into Logs
    values(@userName, @logType, @description, SYSDATETIME());

end
go;
```

I think I remember something similar from Oracle / SQL Plus / PLSQL but I am having trouble finding it.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18.4

Comment: Nope, no such thing. You have to manually update all dependencies.

Comment: You could explore running [`sp_recompile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the results from [`sp_depends`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I suspect that there are a numbers of gotchas to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the TYPEOF feature you're looking for exitsts, but you could try and use a [DDL Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) to keep your procedure in sync with the column type changes.

This trigger would get fired every time a table is altered and you'd just have to parse the EVENTDATA() to see if the column types in the Logs table have changed. The body of your trigger would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnLogsChanged
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    -- 1. Parse EVENTDATA() to see if the Logs table was altered

    -- 2. If it has, store the definition of the WriteLog procedure into a variable by reading it from sys.procedures

    -- 3. Read the new types for the columns of the Logs table from sys.all_columns

    -- 4. replace the parameter declarations in the procedure definition to match the new types in the Logs table

    -- 5. alter the procedure with the new definition by building up the ALTER PROCEDURE statement as a string and executing it with sp_executesql
END
```

As long as the trigger stays enabled your procedure should stay in sync with the table column types.

Comment: This does kind of do what I want, but it adds the complexity of writing the triggers and alter statements every time I want to change a new dbo. It does have the possibility to preserve the data, but I could also just edit the create statement; [use SSMS to generate insert statements from the table's data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515975/7908554); and regenerate the whole database, which would probably be faster in most cases if the test data isn't huge. I think you are correct that what I wan't doesn't exist though.